# Hyperledger Fabric - endorsement based on specific parties involved in the transaction

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm using Fabric along with Composer. I understand that you set the endorsement policy at instantiation. However, if this is the case and I have the following scenario:

Company A says it has moved a physical asset to Company B. I want Company B to be the endorser for the transaction, but company A might have moved it to B, C or D, etc...

Is it therefore possible to dynamically choose the receiving company to be the endorser at runtime?

Comment: This needs to define when you are defining the network. If Company A can transfer something to B, C or D, all those companies must be defined as an organization in the network. Each Organization could have its peers definition( a set of an endorser or a committer peer).

Comment: So is it not possible to use the endorsement scheme to choose only company B to endorse the transaction that company A moved, on the basis that it could be B, C... Z depending on who A chooses to move it to?

Comment: What do you mean by the company here? Is it an organization which is a part of the network, having it's own peers and some anchor peer or it's just a synonym for a participant to whose an asset can be transferred?

Comment: Bit f both? Organisations with own peers and anchor peer. Each organisation can have multiple participants that can receive the asset, but any participant from that organisation would be fine to accept it. But, it's not known at initiation which organisation the asset will go to

Comment: I have answered your question. Hope that helps. If it does, don't forget to accept it.  If it doesn't please feel free to comment so that I can help you in a better way. Happy coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated the answer:

Yes, there is a way to dynamically choose endorser peer based on Endorsement policy. Hyperledger Fabric v1.2 and later, offers a service named as Service Discovery. This service needs to be enabled at a peer level.

Once this is enabled, you can send a transaction to the channel using the service discovery. Service discovery will check the endorsement policy by it's own and sends the transaction proposal to the required endorsers.

Attached a snipped from an JAVA-SDK application:

```
channel.sendTransactionProposalToEndorsers(request,
                 createDiscoveryOptions().setEndorsementSelector(ServiceDiscovery.EndorsementSelector.ENDORSEMENT_SELECTION_RANDOM)
                        .setForceDiscovery(true));
```

There is a **concept of Application SDK** for interacting with your Hyperleger network. If you have multiple organization, each organization needs to have its own SDK. Using that SDK, you can utilize service discovery to locate endorser peers for sending transaction proposals.
Refer this image for reference[image]

Hope this helps.